# ::before - element out of position

Tags: css

I try to reproduce this frosted glass effect ([frosted glass](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/), [codepen](http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/d056d1b26b9683c018f9bb9e0f1b0e1c)).

My problem is, that I can't get the blurred area in position. It always appears slightly shifted to the right (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45t157w1/)).

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

  <style>
    html, body, .glass {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url('pelican.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .glass::before {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('pelican.jpg');
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        background-size: cover;
        content: ' ';
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .glass {
        background-color: white;
    }
    .glass.down {
        transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-20rem);
    }
    .glass.down::before {
        transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(20rem);
    }
    .glass.up, .glass.up::before {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <article class="glass down">
      <h1>Pelican</h1>
      <p>additional content...</p>
    </article>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm quite sure its just a little detail I'm missing here, but I just don't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your body has an inherit margin on it.  Changing that should solve your issue

http://jsfiddle.net/4sf5cmnq/

```
body {  margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Note the margin property is not inherited.

Comment: correction: @Oriol is correct in his statement about it NOT being inherited